# can I use an object's property in the object's method without using `this`

Tags: javascript

In following code, why I cannot access `b` without `this` keyword. I am using `nodejs` to run the code

```
var o = {
    a: 0,
    b:0,
    m1: function(){
        return this.a+b; //this doesn't compile
    },
}
console.log(o.m1())
```

Comment: Because then `b` will be interpreted as a variable, not a property in an object (which is refered to by `this`).

Comment: In the olden days you could use [**`with`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). But its deprecated now.

Answer (score 2):

Change `this.a + b;` to `this.a + this.b;`. There is no variable `b` but there is a property of the object with that name

```js
var o = {
    a: 1,
    b: 4,
    m1: function(){
        return this.a + this.b; 
    },
}
console.log(o.m1())
```

Comment: OP knows he can use `this`. His question is _why?_. So perhaps you should focus on that more.